# $lookup for each element within a sub-array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

So in my Database, I have the 3 collections, and they look like this:

**Customers:**

```
customers = [
  {_id: 1, username: "jack", ... },
  {_id: 2, username: "jane", ... }
  ...
]
```

**Reviews:**

```
reviews = [
  { _id: 1, customerID: 1, message: "my message", ...}
  ...
]
```

**Comments:**

```
comments = [
  { _id: 1, reviewID: 1, customerID: 2, message: "my response" ...}
  ...
]
```

Customers can post reviews, and can also comment on other reviews. 
So, what I want is a mongodb `aggregation` query to:

1. Retrieve the reviews.
2. The data of the customer who made the review.
3. The comments on that review.
4. The data of the customers who made the comment on that review.

**i.e**

```
reviews = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    username: "jack",
    message: "my message"
    comments: [
      { _id: 1, username: "jane", message: "my response", ...},
      ...
    ]
    ...
  }
  ...
]
```

Comment: I know this isn't what you're asking, but you're structuring your data in a really relational (i.e. not mongo friendly) way, and that's why you're running into a problem where the only solution is doing two `$lookup`s for what looks like a common query. The more standard mongo-y way of solving this would be to have a `reviews` collection that looks similar to your final output with denormalized usernames on the comments in the comments array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from `comments` collection and [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) with `customers` to get `customer` name, then you can [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) all comments by review and [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)  twice (with `reviews` and `customer`). Every time you know that it's a one-to-one relationship you can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) after [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). Try:

```
db.comments.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "customers",
            localField: "customerID",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "customer"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$customer"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            reviewID: 1,
            username: "$customer.username",
            message: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$reviewID",
            comments: { $push: { _id: "$_id", username: "$username", message: "$message" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "reviews",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "review"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$review"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "customers",
            localField: "review.customerID",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "customer"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$customer"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            message: "$review.message",
            username: "$customer.username",
            comments: 1
        }
    }
])
```

Outputs:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "comments" : [ { "_id" : 1, "username" : "jane", "message" : "my response" } ], "message" : "my message", "username" : "jack" }
```

EDIT:
If you want to start from `reviews` and filter it out to single movie you can then you can use [$lookup with custom pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)

```
db.reviews.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            movieId: 1,
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "customers",
            localField: "customerID",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "customer"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$customer"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "comments",
            let: { reviewId: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$$reviewId", "$reviewID" ] } }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "customers",
                        localField: "customerID",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "customer"
                    }
                },
                {
                    $unwind: "$customer"
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 1,
                        message: 1,
                        username: "$customer.username"
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "comments"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            message: 1,
            username: "$customer.username",
            comments: 1
        }
    }
])
```

Brings the same output

Comment: This doesn't return the username of the commenters

Comment: @KingsleyKbcComics true, now it should be fine

Comment: Thanks, but I cant start from the comments either. The reviews also have a `movieID` field, and that is the key entered when I make the http request.

Comment: But it wasn't mentioned in your question :)

Comment: I know, sorry about that. But i stated my desired outcome as `"reviews = ..."`

Comment: @KingsleyKbcComics now it should be fine - the same output but probably with better performance

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation with mongodb **3.6** and above

```
Reviews.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Customers.collection.name,
    "let": { "customerID": "$customerID" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$customerID"] } } }
    ],
    "as": "customer"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$customer" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Comments.collection.name,
    "let": { "reviewID": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$reviewID", "$$reviewID"] } } },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Customers.collection.name,
        "let": { "customerID": "$customerID" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$customerID"] } } }
        ],
        "as": "customer"
      }},
      { "$unwind": "$customer" },
    ],
    "as": "comments"
  }}
])
```