# Mongo aggregate lookup documents after group

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am fairly new to MongoDB and getting on well so far.But now iam trying to dive deeper and using aggregate(), but getting slightly confused by it.

I have the following:

```js
  Link.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        eclipseId: link.eclipseId,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'configitems',
        localField: 'autotaskId',
        foreignField: 'id',
        as: 'autotask',
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'companies',
        localField: 'autotask.companyId',
        foreignField: 'id',
        as: 'company',
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'billcharges',
        localField: 'eclipseId',
        foreignField: 'id',
        as: 'eclipse',
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$eclipseId',
        id: { $first: '$_id' },
        company: { $first: { $arrayElemAt: ['$company', 0] } },
        eclipse: { $first: { $arrayElemAt: ['$eclipse', 0] } },
        autotask: { $first: { $arrayElemAt: ['$autotask', 0] } },
        items: {
          $push: '$$ROOT',
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'subscriptions',
        let: { materialCodeID: '$materialCodeID' },
        pipeline: [
          { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$items.autotaskId', '$$materialCodeID'] } } },
        ],
        as: 'subscription2',
      },
    },
     {
       $project: {
         // company: 0,
         items: {
           company: 0,
           eclipse: 0,
           autotask: 0,
         },
       },
     },
  ])
```

I have 3 collections:

- configitems
- companies
- billcharges

`$lookup` on these works just fine, but then i need to group by `eclipseId` and push all that matches into `items` array. So far so good. The problem iam facing is that now i have lets say 4 items in `items` array and i need for each to `lookup` in `subscriptions` collection and save into `subscription` key under relevant item

so i would like to end up with following format:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "_id": "4522",
    "id": "60ec62cc5fe7a94738d30f6b",
    "company": {
      //some data
    },
    "eclipse": {
      //some data
    },
    "autotask": {
      //some data
    },
    "items": [
      {
        "_id": "60ec62cc5fe7a94738d30f6b",
        "subscription": {
          //some data
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": "60ec62cc5fe7a94738d30f6c",
        "subscription": {
          //some data
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried to follow this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54721755/11091571) but to no avail.
ANy help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the amount of **$lookup** you have on your aggregation pipeline, you should really consider to change the architecture of your database. Lookups are very expensive and will slowdown you app's performance. You will be better off reshaping your documents with nested data than splitting into different documents and looking up on an aggregation later.

If I understand your problem correctly, the best solution for the given query would be using the **$unwind** operator just after the last **$group** stage:

```
// Previous code ...

{
  $group: {
    _id: '$eclipseId',
    id: { $first: '$_id' },
    company: { $first: { $arrayElemAt: ['$company', 0] } },
    eclipse: { $first: { $arrayElemAt: ['$eclipse', 0] } },
    autotask: { $first: { $arrayElemAt: ['$autotask', 0] } },
    items: {
      $push: '$$ROOT',
    },
  },
},
{
    $unwind: '$items'
},

...
```

This would create one document for every entry in the **items** array you created during the **$group** stage pushing **$$ROOT**. After unwinding you get an array of documents shaped like this:

```
{
  _id: ...,
  company: ...,
  eclipse: ...,
  autotask: ...,
  items: {
   // Item data,
  },
},
```

Having this data shape you can go ahead and lookup from the subscriptions:

```
// Previous code ...

{
    $unwind: '$items'
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'subscriptions',
    localField: 'items.autotaskId',
    foreignField: 'materialCodeID',
    as: 'subscriptions2',
  },
},
...
```

As result you would have an array of documents with the following structure:

```
{
  _id: ...,
  company: ...,
  eclipse: ...,
  autotask: ...,
  items: {
   // Item data,
  },
  subscriptions2: [ ... ]
},
```

To finalize and shape the data the way you want, you could possibly group by _id and add the property items with subscriptions included like this:

```
 // Previous code ...

 {
   $unwind: '$items'
 },
 {
   $lookup: {
     from: 'subscriptions',
     localField: 'items.autotaskId',
     foreignField: 'materialCodeID',
     as: 'subscriptions2',
   },
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: '$_id',
    company: { $first: '$company'},
    eclipse: { $first: '$eclipse'},
    autotask: { $first: '$autotask'},
    items: { $push: {
      _id: '$items._id',
      subscription: '$subscriptions2',
    }}
  }
},
...
```

I can't assure you this solution will work as I can't reproduce it locally to check how the data is being shaped on the aggregation pipeline, but given your explanation I would do something along this line.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It helped in different way :-) i have restructured the way i use mongo and works fine. Id love to have a chat about this and how to correctly approach mongo structure